# navigation between pages on android back key

Tags: android, navigation, back-button

I am trying to navigate to `selection.html` page on Android back button but it works only one time and then stops all navigations on back key event.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.open("selection.html");
    }, false );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).on("navigate", function (event, data) {
    var direction = data.state.direction;
    if (direction == 'back') {
        window.open("index-Eng.html");
    }
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.